# Compile OPC-UA-AnsiC to DLL

Tags: c, visual-c++, opc-ua

my goal is to write a small OPC-UA-Client in Delphi and i want to use the original [OPC-UA-Stack](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-AnsiC) without any 3rd-party-SDK.

I am already able to compile the Ansi-C-Stack but the output are .obj and .lib files.

Is there a way to compile the stack to a DLL? I already tried do use link.exe to create a DLL from the Obj-Files but I get a lot of "unresolved external symbol" error messages, some of them i was able to resolve, but not all.

I also tried to use the obj. files directly in delphi, but then i have a lot of manual translation work.

Comment: You need to resolve the missing dependencies

Comment: So using the link.exe is the correct way to create a DLL?

Comment: @Mr.Dev: How you turn a set of .obj and .lib files into a DLL is dependent on the system you are using (gpp, VC++, C++Builder, etc.). It should be described somewhere in the documentation. But is this really a Delphi question?

Comment: It was a Delphi question, since the original problem was how to make the stack usable in Delphi. Compiling it as DLL is the first part of the process - and this is not really explained in the project, although it is possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can compile it as a DLL with Visual Studio. In the project Properties, change the Configuration Type to .dll and also add the define '_UA_STACK_BUILD_DLL'.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i have searched for

Comment: Maybe you can mark it as the right answer then, despite all the negative feedback we got ;)